# Flutter plugin: InAppPurchasePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, androidx

When i am trying to just add the in_app_purchase plugging in the apps pubspec.yaml file the following error is occurred.

Just after adding the plugin. not related to any specific code.

```
Note: /Users/tanzimfahim/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/in_app_purchase-0.2.0+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/inapppurchase/InAppPurchasePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: As described in your log message this is not an Error, but simply a "Note" on the console. The build will typically be successful, unless there are any other errors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Unchecked or unsafe operations

When adding plugins to Flutter and running your app *on **Android***, you will often see warnings. The "unchecked or unsafe operations" warning is very common.

### They are fine

You **do not have to worry about it** because:

- This is just a *warning*, not an *error*. These warnings will only appear when you compile the plugin for the first time, i.e. every time you use `flutter clean` or add a new plugin; generally when you compile a plugin for the first time.
- Most plugins, certainly all [Flutter favorites](https://pub.dev/flutter/favorites), are **tested**. If *unchecked or unsafe* operations are left in, the authors have determined that these operations are fine in their use case.

#### What can you do about them?

As I outlined above, you do *not have to do anything* about them.

What you can do is [file an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new) about it or [create a pull request](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pulls) directly to either **suppress** the warning or find an alternative solution in code.

Comment: "This is just a warning, not an error" is not a very good philosphy to foollow. THe compiler generates an warning because there is a potential problem which may not break your app right away but may become a bottoleneck in future.