# Flutter Warning when build release

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I keep on getting these red warning when i try to build --release my app:
tried flutter clean.........
flutter clean --cache nothing is working, all packages are up-to-date.

My build Gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

These Red Warning comes First:

```
 C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.8.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    Note: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.6.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

---

```
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/96912e3e4984bdc463916ea6fba56ac4/transformed/jetified-activity-1.7.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0c21f8311e0d3bdd149fde1cccd7c6b/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-core-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/57c255789025aac2fb6743aca74eb9ff/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/dfe23d076662816f417c59321ede171a/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4fec81ebf7b0698db38977ed6bdfb196/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a45d532d047b5ee2ada4d44d5157d37f/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9d8fb97b2a99c1b1d78bd925837bcbf3/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.      
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9c576e910ff1e555ef5f56b5c13b0097/transformed/lifecycle-runtime-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.6.1/10f354fdb64868baecd67128560c5a0d6312c495/lifecycle-common-2.6.1.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/134cbae0d4fd6d050de78674ca51ac81/transformed/jetified-savedstate-1.2.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/savedstate_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
```

Comment: You may check this [uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942236/flutter-plugin-inapppurchaseplugin-java-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations)

Comment: ok I solve this same issue today on my code this issue is related when you connect the Firebase connection 
 1. add this under the dependency file: android/build.gradle

  

     classpath ‘com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3’

  2.then go to android/app/build.gradle you will find 

    defaultConfig{
      applicationId "com.yourapp.com"
      //Then add this
       minSdkVersion 22
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
       versionName flutterVerionName
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution for gradle problem
Just used Android studio and opened Gradle file in android directory.
when opened in android studio, the IDE would have option to open with it.
once you click on it android studio would automatically download the gradle version needed and ask you if u want to update.

If the gradle build showed a failed or errors, then flutter clean and redo.

Answer (score 1):

1. flutter upgrade
2. There is a new version on Android Studio => go to website and download
3. Update Sdk and all
4. android/build.gradle => classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
5. if not flutter clean => 4 .
   It solved mine.

Comment: already latest update, already tried clean even clean cache. nothing working

Comment: I dont know,  changing build.gradle solved : android/build.gradle => classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15' 
We had so similar issue . I am sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following lines to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

This should allow the build to continue even when warnings are found. However, this is not a long-term solution and it is recommended to investigate and resolve the warnings when possible.

Additionally, try running flutter pub cache clean in your terminal. This command cleans your Flutter and Dart package cache which might help with the build issues.

Comment: tried, same problem

Comment: are you running kotlin compat compile??

if so, try this:

ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22' 
 on build.gradle

Comment: i have this
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
yet same problem

Comment: @MarceSanchezMelgar try this ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
It is the latest Kotlin version

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the Gradle cache directory (`C:/Users/PC/.gradle/caches/`)?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is in your `build.gradle` file change the **minSdkVersion** to version **22** and **targetSdkVersion**  to version **33**, then run the app again it will work fine.

Comment: still this errorNote: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.8.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.6.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java

Comment: Try to use the latest firebase APIs version https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android